# How to obtain an unencrypted private key from an encrypted private key?

Tags: key, private

I can't find any way to get the unencrypted private key from an encrypted private key from the tezos client.

I have found a way using tezbox. You import a private key into tezbox and then show the private key. The key that it shows you is unencrypted. I am unable to import an encrypted private key into tezbox that has a 'blank' password so this method is not available to me.

I have been told I can use [eztz](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz) using:

```
eztz.crypto.extractEncryptedKeys('edesk','password')`
```

And I have been told I can use [pytezos](https://github.com/murbard/pytezos) using:

```
Key(key='edesk...', passphrase='123456').secret_key()
```

I can't figure out how to get the above options to work, though. I have tried the eztz node.js method, but I would appreciate an example of how to do this.

Comment: You need to import eztz lib first and then use this:
```eztz.crypto.extractEncryptedKeys(encryptedPrivateKey, password)```
It will return a full set of extracted keys.

Comment: Btw, that function is used on client side, will not work if you are using it on backend as it needs the window obj.

You need to change it to work on backend.

Answer (score 5):

With [pytezos](https://github.com/murbard/pytezos)

```
import pytezos
print(pytezos.Key('edesk...', passphrase='yourpassword').secret_key())
```

**UPD**

```
>>> from pytezos import Key
>>> key = Key.generate()
>>> key.public_key_hash()
'tz1hQbcSWjcWLdcRjMDqpJVuTaaj9m2wMtwk'
>>> esk = key.secret_key(passphrase='12345'.encode())
>>> esk
'edesk1UrFQK6xJM6SYdLxMQbyKaaYQmzYVvQRpJXUmxj3apZ1ufRu4aHSTqWrJiqcHywSbnF146wkNcpUAW7Qy6H'
>>> Key.from_encoded_key(esk, passphrase='12345'.encode()).secret_key()
'edsk2juUM8ZMUkaCKHWVnzWhp9DxrK93YK1rQjYk3pTEq2ThXpBxkX'
```

According to the developer: "Passing password as bytes is not convenient indeed, plain string support will be added to mitigate this."

Comment: im getting this error :   


```
File "/Users/user/Desktop/privkeyconvert/pytezos.py", line 54
    def __init__(self, key: str, passphrase: str = None, email: str = None):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pytezos' has no attribute 'key'. running in the python3 cli

Comment: same issue here 'pytezos' has no attribute 'key'...

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read [this guide](http://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/21/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-signing-operations/). There is some Python code inside.

Comment: link is dead... can you provide a new link?

Answer (score 0):

With [pytezos](https://github.com/murbard/pytezos) :

```
from pytezos.crypto import Key
print(Key('edesk....', passphrase='pasword...').secret_key())
```